# WordPress no themes or plugins detected

Tags: wordpress, permissions, themes

I have this WordPress and it works just fine on the remote server i downloaded the same files and database dump and tried to make it work locally with xampp but when i try to open the local site i get a white screen and when i log in to wp-admin i get that the theme directory does not exist and there is no themes or plugins detected i tried all sort of things (giving write and read permissions to the user) but nothing is working i keep getting the same error and i can't upload new themes getting the message upload failed couldn't create directory what are the possible solution to such problem i feel it should be basic but i just get around to it.

OS : windows10 64bit

Answer (score 0):

> WordPress works fine on remote server

If WordPress workd fine on remote server and not in your new domain than I think you have not moved Wordpress properly. Please delete files and drop table from your new domain and refer https://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress

And than try to move WordPress from existing domain.

Let me know if you need anything else...

Comment: i tried following this step by step still it's not working the problem is that the theme still can't be detected and i still can't upload a theme cues for some reason it says that it can't create the directory.

Comment: Can i take a look on your domain?